# Adding title beside raster spplot legend

Tags: raster, r, legend

After studying for a while how to create a chart from a raster object, I got almost everything I needed except to add a title to spplot's legend.

What I tried:

1. To use `mtext("XXX (m)", side=4)`.
2. To add a `sp.text` outside the grid.
3. To use `legend.args = list(title="XXX (m)")`.

The below picture pinpoints the feature I added manually to my plot, and in which I would like to include using R.

[image]

Here is one example of what I got so far:

```
require(raster)
require(sp)
require(lattice)

north <- list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(type=1), offset = c(0.95,0.85), scale=0.1)
scale <- list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(),
      offset = c(0.55, 0.03), scale = 0.4, fill = c("transparent","black"))
txt1 <- list("sp.text", c(0.55, 0.08), "0")
txt2 <- list("sp.text", c(0.75, 0.08), "0.2")
txt3 <- list("sp.text", c(0.95, 0.08), "0.4")
raster_layout <- list(north,scale,txt1,txt2,txt3)
cuts <- c(110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200)
spplot(raster(volcano), scales = list(draw=T), at=cuts, col.regions = palette(gray(seq(0,0.9,len=9))), sp.layout= raster_layout, add=T)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `mtext` here, because `spplot` is based on the [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) package. `mtext` can only be used with base graphics.

```
R> p <- spplot(raster(volcano), scales = list(draw=T), at=cuts,
+              col.regions = palette(gray(seq(0,0.9,len=9))),
+              sp.layout= raster_layout, add=T)
R> class(p)
[1] "trellis"  # -> lattice package
```

The `lattice` package makes use of the `grid` graphics engine, which is a  low-level graphics system for R. Both packages are part of the base R distribution.

To add a text label at an arbitrary position you can use the function `grid.text`, e.g.

```
library("grid")
grid.text("XXX (m)", x=unit(0.95, "npc"), y=unit(0.50, "npc"), rot=-90)
```